# file downloaded from my html page arrives empty

Tags: html, file, download, href

B"H

this is my code:
< a href="FileName.XlsX" download>download file</a

when user click the "download file" he should get the file.

In local host, it works good.

but in real site, the file arrives empty. why?

Comment: Your code example is not proper - please fix it (see here for examples https://www.sitepoint.com/new-html5-attributes-hyperlinks-download-media-ping/ - and why has your file such strange case? filename.xlsx would be best - what you think?

Comment: Can you publish the URL of the real site? Thanks.

Comment: the syntax in your code is off.  there should not be a space between the opening bracket and the `a` and you don't have a closing bracket for the `</a`.  Read the instructions for posting code and provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  DO NOT post the URL of the real site @Lumito.

Comment: @ChrisL OK. I will not ask it again. Thanks.